# Lotusscript: Use variable as array name so can apply function in a loop

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am not sure if I phrased the question well. Here is what I want to accomplish.

My agent builds a series of 25 or so arrays. Arr1() and Arr(2) etc. They are dynamic as I do not know how many items they will contain.

The agent must apply several functions to each array. One simple one is a bubble sort.

So I have 25 lines of code like this:

```
Call bub_sort(Arr1)
Call bub_sort(Arr2)
etc.
```

For each function I have 25 lines of code like that (or similar code).

Over time I will add additional arrays and possibly different functions.

Seems like it would be better to Load a List or Array of the array names, and then iterate over that for the functions, like so

```
'Sort Arrays
ForAll lst In lstGrpNme
    Call bub_sort(lst)
End Forall
```

However, the code of course doesn't work as I am passing the string, not an array.

How can I get around this?

I fear that I will have to make a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example of when a class would be very useful.

> *I fear that I will have to make a class?*

Don't be afraid, classes are actually very easy. I wrote two blog entries about this a while back, take a look if you like:
http://blog.texasswede.com/object-oriented-lotusscript-for-beginners-part-1/
http://blog.texasswede.com/object-oriented-lotusscript-for-beginners-part-2/

Since you think you might add more functions later, you should build this as a class.
Then you could do something like this:

```
Set myArray = New MyArrayClass(arr1,arr2)
Call myArray.bubbleSort
```

Comment: All of the responses were very helpful. I have went with Knut's suggestion for now, but I am going to read your posts soon and make some mods to my code to make it a full class. I have written full class based code in LS before, and in other languages, I just am not as comfortable in LS using classes, but the only way to get more comfortable is to do it!

Answer (score 4):

You can create an `Variant` array of all arrays and iterate through all with `Forall`:

```vb
Dim Array1(10) As String
Array1(0) = "one"
...
Dim Array2(10) As String
Array2(0) = "two"
...
Dim AllArrays(25) As Variant
AllArrays(0) = Array1
AllArrays(1) = Array2
...
Forall Array In AllArrays
    If Not Isempty(Array) Then
        If Ubound(Array) > 0 Then
            Print(Array(0))   ' prints every array's first element
            Call bub_sort(Array)
        End If
    End If
End Forall
```

You can omit the two `If` lines if you are sure that every element of AllArrays is filled and that every array has at least one element.

You could use a **List** instead of an array in a similar way too. Just change this one Dim line:

```vb
Dim AllArrays List As Variant
```

Instead of numbers 0, 1, 2, ... you could give arrays names and access them later with the name.

```vb
Const ARRAY_ONE = 0
Const ARRAY_TWO = 1
AllArrays(ARRAY_ONE) = Array1
AllArrays(ARRAY_TWO) = Array2
...
Dim TmpArray As Variant
TmpArray = AllArrays(ARRAY_ONE)
TmpArray(0) = "xxx"
AllArrays(ARRAY_ONE) = TmpArray
```

Comment: This will work, but once the I load the AllArrays, any change in the "sub" Arrays are not reflected in the AllArrays. So if I do a     Array1(1) = "two" after the End Forall, that value will not print if I did the Forall again. I think this will help me, but it would be nice for this to be dynamic.

Comment: You can change a value in an array this way dynamically:    `TmpArray = AllArrays(0)` 
`TmpArray(0) = "xxx"`
`AllArrays(0) = TmpArray`

Answer (score 0):

If you want literally to pass a string as array name then you can use [`Execute`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_EXECUTE_FUNCTION_AND_STATEMENT.html) statement. For this you must put all your array variables to `(Declarations)` section of your agent.
Here is example:

```vb
`Declarations
Dim tempArray As Variant 'This is temp array for performing operations
Dim array0 As Variant
Dim array1 As Variant
'... and so on

Sub Initialize

'...
    Dim arrayNames() As String

    Redim array0(2) As Integer
    Redim array1(1) As Integer

    array0(0) = 0
    array0(1) = 1
    array0(2) = 2

    array1(0) = 3
    array1(1) = 4

    Redim arrayNames(1) As String
    arrayNames(0) = "array0"
    arrayNames(1) = "array1"

    'Do something with all arrays
    Forall arrayName In arrayNames
        Call GetArray(arrayName)
        Call DoSomethingWithArray(tempArray)
        Call SetArray(arrayName)
    End Forall
'...

End Sub

'Put array to tempArray
Sub GetArray(arrayName As String)
    Execute "tempArray = " & arrayName$
End Sub

'Put tempArray to array
Sub SetArray(arrayName As String)
    Execute arrayName$ & " = tempArray"
End Sub

'Some function
Sub DoSomethingWithArray(array As Variant)
    For index% = 0 To Ubound(array)
        array(index%) = array(index%) + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of Arrays and/or a Class like this:

```
%REM
 Description: NOT TESTET! JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION!
%END REM
Public Class ArrayHandler
    Private ArrayList() As Variant
    Private ArrayListCounter As Long

    %REM
        Sub New
        Description: Constructor
    %END REM
    Public sub New(firstArray As Variant)
        ArrayListCounter = 0
        ReDim Preserve ArrayList(ArrayListCounter) As Variant
        ArrayList(ArrayListCounter) = firstArray
    End Sub
    %REM
        Sub addArray
        Description: self Explaining... ;)
    %END REM
    Public Sub addArray(nexArray As Variant)
        ArrayListCounter = ArrayListCounter + 1
        ReDim Preserve ArrayList(ArrayListCounter) As Variant
        ArrayList(ArrayListCounter) = nexArray
    End Sub

    %REM
        Sub bub_sort_allArrays
        Description: The Magic Function! ;-)
    %END REM
    Public Sub bub_sort_allArrays()
        ForAll arrs In ArrayList
            Call bub_sort(arrs)
        End ForAll
    End Sub

    %REM
        Sub bub_sort
        Description: YOUR FUNCTION!
    %END REM
    Public Sub bub_sort(Arr As Variant)
        '//-- YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this will help you. :)

EDIT:
A second more fitting idea, maybe...:

```
Public Class ArrayHandler
Private ArrayList List As Variant

%REM
    Sub New
    Description: Constructor
%END REM
Public sub New(firstArray As Variant, firstArrayName As String)
    ArrayList(firstArrayName) = firstArray
End Sub
%REM
    Sub addArray
    Description: self Explaining... ;)
%END REM
Public Sub addArray(nexArray As Variant, nextArrayName As String)
    ArrayList(nextArrayName) = nexArray
End Sub

%REM
    Sub bub_sort_allArrays
    Description: The Magic Function! ;-)
%END REM
Public Sub bub_sort_allArrays()
    ForAll arrs In ArrayList
        Call bub_sort(ListTag(arrs))
    End ForAll
End Sub

%REM
    Sub bub_sort
    Description: YOUR FUNCTION!
%END REM
Public Sub bub_sort(Arr As Variant)
    '//-- YOUR CODE GOES HERE
End Sub
```

End Class